# orientationchange event jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, orientation-changes

Okay so here is my code.

```
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
alert('1');
if (event.orientation == 'landscape'){
    alert('2');
    $('.item').css('width', '30.66%');   
} else if (event.orientation == 'portrait') {
    $('.item').css('width', '47%');   
}
});

$(document).on('ready', function () {
    $( window ).orientationchange(); 
});
```

I'm simply trying to change the width of my objects named .item. I looked up syntax for orientationchange on jQuery mobile and it appears to be right. Now I'm getting my first alert every time I change the orientation as expected but I'm not getting inside the if statement. From what I read you access the orientation with event.orientation and it's equal to 'portrait' or 'landscape' but it doesn't seem to working for me. 
The last part is just so that the function gets called as soon as the page loads which is always working fine. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried checking the value with `alert(event.orientation);`?

Comment: I just tried that and I'm getting undefined with seems weird.

Comment: I've expereinced flaky behaviour on some devices as well. I'd suggest just using the window resize event instead http://api.jquery.com/resize/

I think I found that sometimes the event.orientation value doesn't actually change until sometime after the event is triggered. I tried delaying the action slightly using setTimout but found the resize event worked better.

Furthermore, just had a closer look at what you're trying to do. You might be better off using CSS media queries here.

Comment: @pantryfight - I think you're right. You should add an answer using media queries!

Answer (score 0):

Orientation is a property of the `window.screen` object, not the event. Try

`if (window.screen.orientation.indexOf('landscape') >= 0){...}`

Since this is an emerging standard, you might also have to check vendor specific implementations, e.g. `window.screen.mozOrientation`

**References**

- [Orientation event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/orientationchange)
- [Window.screen object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.screen)
- [Orientation property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.screen.orientation)